# SQL server 2012 on Windows server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I know this is a basic question. but I can't find any answer on the internet. I know SQL server 2012 is running on Windows 2012 server but when I look at the start page (it has IE, Control panel, task manager and etc). but how do I start SQL server 2012 that is running on this server?

Comment: `SQL Server Management Studio` is the program you want to find to open a connection to your SQL Service. If the service is not yet running, you must start it via `Services.msc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start->Run (Windows R if you prefer) `SQLServerManager11.msc`

That is the snapin for managing your SQL Server Instances.

[image: Sql Server Configuration Manager]

Unless of course you mean SQL Server Management Studio which by default would be installed at `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to do this.

One way is just to open up the metro home screen and type "Sql".  You should see a list of matching applications, one of which is the "SQL server manager".

Launch it, click "SQL Server Services" in the tree on the left hand side and you should see a service called "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" in the list on the right hand side.  Right click it and choose "start".

I believe you should configure the service to auto start when Windows starts, unless there's a specific reason you don't want SQL server running all the time on the machine.